# Динамическое создание экземпляров объекта и выделение каких-то конкретных

Tags: javascript

Допустим, у меня есть модуль галереи.

**gallery.js**

```
class Gallery {
    constructor(gallery, options) {
        this.gallery = gallery;
        this.options = options || {};
        this.getOptions();
    }

    getOptions(options) {
        // что-то делаем с нашими оциями
    }
}

module.exports = Gallery;
```

На странице может быть сколько угодно галерей. В нашем примере пускай их будет 3, но в жизни может быть и 10.

**index.html**

```
<div class="j-gallery">...</div>
<div class="j-gallery">...</div>
<div class="j-gallery">...</div>
```

Теперь в своем основном файле я создаю экземпляры галерей

**app.js**

```
import Gallery from '../../components/gallery';
const gallerys = document.querySelectorAll('.j-gallery');

for (let i = 0; i < gallerys.length; i++) {
    var gallery =  new Gallery(gallerys[i]);
}
```

Теперь представим, что второй галереи мне нужно добавить каких-нибудь опций, которые поменяют её вид, а у остальных галерей пускай опции будут по умолчанию.
Получается мне в html как-то надо выделить мою галерею с другими опциями.

**index.html**

```
<div class="j-gallery">...</div>
<div class="j-gallery" data-id="otherOptions">...</div>
<div class="j-gallery">...</div>
```

и поправить app.js

**app.js**

```
import Gallery from '../../components/gallery';
const gallery = document.querySelectorAll('.j-gallery');

for (let i = 0; i < gallery.length; i++) {
    if (gallery[i].dataset.id === 'otherOptions') {
        var gallery =  new Gallery(banks[i], { /*special options*/});
    } else {
        var gallery =  new Gallery(banks[i]);
    }
}
```

У меня вопрос во взрослом программирование так и происходит? Что если мне надо из 10 галерей 3 каким-то образом выделить, получается надо на создавать `if`'ов в `for`?

**app.js**

```
import Gallery from '../../components/gallery';
const gallery = document.querySelectorAll('.j-gallery');

for (let i = 0; i < gallery.length; i++) {
    if (gallery[i].dataset.id === 'options') {
        var gallery = new Gallery(gallery, /*options*/);
    } else if (gallery[i].dataset.id === 'otherOptions') {
        var gallery = new Gallery(gallery, /*otherOptions*/);
    } else if (gallery[i].dataset.id === 'otherOtherOptions') {
        var gallery = new Gallery(gallery, /*otherOtherOptions*/);
    } else {
        var gallery = new Gallery(gallery);
    }
}
```

Comment: вы хотите уникально выделить некоторые галереи или дать им какие-то категории?

Comment: Скорее всего и то и то. Из 10 галерей у меня может быть одна уникальная, 2 группы по 2 галереи и 5 оставшихся по умолчанию.

Comment: в таком случае да, для уникального назначать id, а группам уникальный класс, а потом также как вы написали, делать проверки

Comment: Думаю в разметке можно использовать модификаторы из методологии BEM, чтобы обозначать отличия галерей. А в коде применить какие-нибудь паттерны для добавления или модификации поведения обычного класса галереи.

Comment: Тут больше вопрос не к разметке, сам использую БЭМ, а в JS. Отличить галереи в разметке достаточно просто - модификатором.

Comment: в значении атрибута вполне могут быть сами опции, а не просто id, тогда все сведется к получению объекта из data-атрибута, и расширение опций по умолчанию полученным объектом

Comment: Да, хорошая идея. Обдумаю её. Спасибо.